# Is this a compound sentence?

Tags: complex-sentences, compound-sentences

> Well the first thing you have to do is to make sure that the car is on a reasonably level piece of ground and that the ground itself is fairly firm.

Answer (score 3):

No: it's built as

- a single independent clause headed by ***is***, with

  - a subject (*The first thing*) modified by a relative clause (*[which] you have to do*), and
  - a complement consisting of

    - an infinitival clause headed by ***make***, with

      - an implied subject *[you]*,
      - an object consisting of two conjoined content clauses *that the car is on a reasonably level piece of ground* and *that the ground itself is fairly firm*, and
      - an object complement *sure*
    - (Alternatively, you could regard the content clauses as conjunct complements of *sure*.)

It's a complex sentence, not a compound sentence.

Answer (score 2):

## Compound  *versus* Complex

No, it isn’t. That’s because a compound anything has two or more of that thing connected by a conjunction.

- A compound ***subject*** has two or more subjects governing the same predicate.
- A compound ***predicate*** has two or more predicates governed by the same subject.
- A compound ***sentence*** has two or more sentences — read, two or more **independent** clauses.

Your sentence is none of these things:

- It has a single subject: *the first thing*
- It has a single predicate: *is (to make sure...)*
- It has a single independent clause of the stated subject and predicate: *the first thing is* (...)

What you *do* have, however, is a **complex** sentence. A complex sentence has **dependent** clauses. You have several of those.